# how to create Topology table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, topology

i have gis database called Madar in pgadmin with postgis and pgrouting extension, all the data inside gis database already inserted by shp2postgre tool , what i really need now is how to make topology table for routing ?

Comment: There is pretty good documentation: http://pgrouting.org/documentation.html I recommend going through the workshop - you learn a lot about the ins and outs of pgrouting, the data, and functions...